# Eliminating variables from system of equation using Eliminate or Solve

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, parametric-functions

I have a system of equations for algebraic curve given by the zero locus of some polynomial encoded in the system of equations (I want to eliminate variable z and get algebraic curve in terms of x and y, C12 and C22 can be assumed to be integers and even positive if that helps):

```
Eliminate[{y == z^(2 + 2 C12)/(-x^2 + z^2), 
1 == ((x - z) (x/z)^(2 C12) z^(-2 - 2 C12 + 2 C22) (x + z))/(-1 + 
z^2)}, {z}]
```

`Eliminate::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Eliminate, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.`

However Mathematica can't eliminate z.

When I use Solve I get:

`Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.`

Maple gives some answers but they aren't very useful, for instance they don't give algebraic curve that I want.

Is there any smart way to do what I want?

Comment: You are raising `z` to a symbolic power so this is not an algebraic curve. Even assuming it is positive and integral does not make it one (it becomes a parametrized family of such curves).

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. To obtain a family of curves indexed by C's, given by some zero locus polynomial of y and x where their powers depend on C's, but not in the form of this system but in the form of zero locus of some polynomial. Is this possible?

Comment: Offhand I do not know how to do that. There has been some work on Groebner bases parametrized by exponents, but I don't think it ever went far enough to do this.

Comment: Can you give me some reference?

Comment: [1](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1005330) [2](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.4.4175) [3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&ved=0ahUKEwjBsv7qpdTSAhVj4IMKHRVWAww4ChAWCCcwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.csd.uwo.ca%2F~watt%2Fpub%2Freprints%2F2007-saga-sparsesympoly.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFmrL9ylFYsf-FjsOUUxLyffaNFXQ&sig2=qZKgWZD1QkZzsRSQZSTTRg) [4](https://www.tib.eu/de/suchen/id/ieee%3Adoi~10.1109%252FICCSA.2008.38/Groebner-Basis-for-Polynomials-with-Parametric/?tx_tibsearch_search%5Bsearchspace%5D=tn)