# Groebner bases with symbolic exponents

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, parametric-functions, groebner-bases

I'm trying to eliminate variables using Groebner bases or polynomial resultants with symbolic exponents. I'm wondering if it is possible to do it in general case for non-negative integers $C_{ij}$.

Here's my system of equations:

```
P = z^(C12 + 1) x^(C11) (-1)^(C11) - y z^(C11 + 1) + y x z^(C11)
Q = z^(2 C12 + 2) - 
    z^(2 C12 + 1) + (-1)^(1 - C11 + C22) x^(C12 - C11) (x-z) z^(C22 + C11)
```

I want to eliminate variable `z` to get parametric family of algebraic curves in variables x,y indexed by $C_{ij}$. For example, if power of z is linear in this set of equations like in case $C_{12}=C_{22}$ we get algebraic curve: $$  A(x,y) = (-1)^{C_{11}} x^{C_{11}} ((-1)^{C_{12}+1} x^{C_{12}}+y)^{1 - C_{11} + C_{12}} + y^{1 - C_{11} + C_{12}} ( (-1)^{C_{12}} x^{C_{12}} + (x-1)y) $$

My question is: is it possible to solve this system for general non-negative integers $C_{ij}$ ? If not, why?

Comment: This is a math rather than Mathematica question.

Comment: Also this is a duplicate of your previous question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139903/eliminating-variables-from-system-of-equation-using-eliminate-or-solve). The situation laid out in the comments there has not changed.